# How can i get the window title as well ion this code

Tags: c#, audio, cscore

im triying to get the peak value of a window, i did it using the code below, but i need to be able to get the window name as well is there a way to implement this in a basic way  ?

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {
            using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {
                foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    {
                        if (audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue() >= 0.09)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you if u can give me a hand in this project

Comment: Just an FYI, you can make your code a little cleaner by stacking the using statements, you dont need to encapsulate each in curly brackets

Comment: thanks, its just a quick thing i make and need to be able to get the title name window aswell

Comment: You don't seem to have any windows in your code?